# How to detect which NSTableView is selected

Tags: macos, nstableview, xcode5.1

I have an NSViewController with 4 NSTableViews inside (View based),

[image]

all of them have NSTextFields and I want to call a method for triggering an action after editing each of them called

```
-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj{
    NSTextField *textfield = (NSTextField *) [obj object]{}
```

but for do so, I need to know which NSTableView am I editing, what's the proper way to get that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this:

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionIsChanging:(NSNotification *)notification{

    MyTableView *tableView = (MyTableView *)[notification object];

    if (tableView == _tableView1) { NSLog(@"_tableView1"); }
    if (tableView == _tableView2) { NSLog(@"_tableView2"); }
    if (tableView == _tableView3) { NSLog(@"_tableView3"); }
    if (tableView == _tableView4) { NSLog(@"_tableView4"); }   
}
```